# "Good Day" Exam Problem (Probability)

Tags: probability

Alice is getting ready for an important exam.

The exam is conducted by 5 examiners. Alice will pass the exam if at least 3 of the examiners pass her.

Alice is concerned about the possibility of having a "good" day or a "bad" day.

Alice figures that if she has a "good" day, then each of her examiners will pass her, independently of each other, with probability 0.8, whereas if she has a "bad" day, this probability will be reduced to 0.4.

Alice feels that she is twice as likely to have a "bad" day as she is to have a "good" day.

What is the **probability** that Alice has a "good" day if she passes the exam?

Comment: With slightly more work than you have shown so far, I would estimate the answer to be "pretty big." Passing the exam on a bad day seems much less likely than on a good day, which the factor 2 does not compensate for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_j$ be the random variable representing examiner $j$, $E$ be the number of examiners passing her and $D$ be the type of day (either $G$ for good or $B$ for bad). Assume the examiners are independent. Then we need to find the probability

$P(D = G \mid \text{at least 3 examiners pass her}) = P(D = G \mid E \ge 3)$.

You can then use Bayes formula:

$P(D = G \mid E \ge 3) = \frac{P(E \ge 3 \mid D = G) \cdot P(D=G)}{P(E \ge 3 \mid D = G) \cdot P(D=G) + P(E \ge 3 \mid D = B) \cdot P(D=B)}$.

Note that by independence of the examiners, $E \mid \{D=G\}$ is binomially distributed with parameters $5$ and $P(D=G)$, and $E \mid \{D=B\}$ is binomially distributed with parameters $5$ and $P(D=B)$.

Comment: I understood the Bayes formula part, but I'm quite confused about the parameters. I know that P(D=G) = 0.8 and P(D=B) = 0.4, but how do we express P(E 'equal or more than' given G)? And how do we account for the information that there is twice as likely to have a "bad" day as she is to have a "good" day?

Comment: From you original post, you wanted to find the probability that Alice has a good day **if** she passes the exam. So the information we use for the conditioning is "Passes the exam", which is the event $\{E \ge 3\}$. For the second part, you've already accounted for it being twice as likely to be a bad day than a good one by setting $P(D=B) = 2/3$ and $P(D=G) = 1/3$